# Why are expressions like cts:search()/Xpath not plannable in Marklogic?

Tags: marklogic

Using xdmp:plan one can view plans for cts:search() and searchable Xpaths. But why expressions such as  `cts:search()/Xpath` are not plannable ?
Also, I would ask the same question for `cts:uri-match()`.

Comment: If you want help optimizing a particular expression, ask a question with a testable version of it and someone may be able to help.

Comment: I asked the question for general understanding.I would certainly post a few expressions in future. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

[`xdmp:plan`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:plan) and [`xdmp:plannable`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:plannable) look like normal functions, but they aren't really, because they don't look at the value of their arguments, they look at them as expressions and only certain expressions can be examined by those functions. In fact, the only expressions xdmp:plan/plannable can examine are [`cts:search`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:search) and XPath expressions.

If `xdmp:plannable` says that a specific `cts:search` of XPath expression is not plannable, it is because executing it would have raised an error or because the path argument to `cts:search` is not a searchable expression.

Why would a path expression not be searchable? Typically this means it starts with a variable, and doesn't take the whole database as the context. `cts:search` is itself a special form, because it also doesn't just evaluate the first argument and then apply the query to that set (if it did, it would be
very slow over large databases; if you want that kind of functionality, use [`cts:contains`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:contains)). Instead it examines the path expression and incorporates it into the query. You will see this in the plans.

Comment: Thanks ,that was helpful. My notion is if an expression is not plannable it cannot resolve  the fragments from  the indexes  and hence is inefficient. Now, <code>xdmp:plan(cts:uri-match(“regex”))</code> returns <code>XDMP-UNSEARCHABLE</code> despite the fact that cts:uri-match uses the uri lexicon(range indexes). Again, although <code>cts:search(/root,cts:and-query(()))/child</code> seems to be ‘index resolvable’ ,running <code>xdmp:plan()</code> on it returns <code>XDMP-UNSEARCHABLE</code> .It gives me the idea that <code> cts:search(/root,cts:and-query(()))/child</code> is not efficient.

Comment: It's complicated: xdmp:plan isn't as general-purpose as you might assume. Per https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:plan the expression must be "a partially searchable XPath expression or a cts:search() expression.". Now `cts:search(/a, 'fubar')` is a cts:search expression. But `cts:search(/a, 'fubar')/b` is not: it's an XPath expression with a cts:search subexpression, and apparently it isn't partially searchable. A call to `cts:uri-match` does not qualify either. Future releases might change this. Even today `xdmp:query-trace` can trace some lookups that xdmp:plan can't - and vice versa.

Comment: Ok. That's helpful.Thanks.